# Nikon D5300 in manual mode bug

Tags: nikon, camera-settings, nikon-d5300

I am using Nikon D5300 with AF-P Nikkor 18-55mm lens in the manual mode. While changing the shutter speed, it automatically and simultaneously changes the aperture. I find this to be very strange, since I should be able to change the aperture and the shutter speed separately in the manual mode. 
It can not possibly be auto exposure correction as making the shutter faster, actually simultaneously decreases the aperture from f/3.5 to f/4.

Is this a bug or something ? Has anyone else too faced it ?

Comment: Is the *lens* in manual mode (i.e manual focus) or the camera (i.e manual exposure)?

Comment: I'm never sure which is which, but the newer 18-55 kit lenses have no M/A switch at all, it's all done in the camera.

Comment: @PhilipKendall , the lens has no manual/automatic switch. The camera is in the manual mode (manual exposure). Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Is the exposure compensation graph changing when you're setting the exposure. The [manual](https://static.bhphotovideo.com/lit_files/95011.pdf) is a little confusing- says to keep the +/- button pressed while rotating the command dial for both compensation and (elsewhere) manual aperture adjustment.

Comment: Are you sure the camera is not in Program mode ("P" on the mode dial)?

Comment: Are you changing anything else at all? Is automatic ISO enabled? Does it always change in the same way?

Comment: @KamenMinkov Yes, the dial is in the 'M' mode.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce this with a D5300 and an AF-S 18-55mm (not AF-P), it works as expected.

Try to make a factory reset on the camera first, and check if it still happens after. AF-P lenses are optimized for continuous autofocus in video mode, maybe this has something to do with your video settings.

Also contact directly Nikon support for specific gear issues, it's their job to help you.

Comment: Thanks, I will try resetting to factory settings and check

Answer (score 1):

For me it got resolved after I did a reset shooting menu from settings. Apparently some setting was causing this.